# Access selected text (not value) of a select element with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Just trying to access the selected text (not value) of a select element via Vue:

```
var App = window.App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    style: '5'
  },
  computed: {
    calctitle: function() {
      return this.otype.text;
    }
  }
});
```

Just an example style object:

```
$item = new stdClass();
$item->value = 5;
$item->text = 'Name 1';
$style = array($item);
...
```

Here i try to create a binding because if i don't cannot submit the form because the option value is "[object Object]", but i need the real int value.

```
<p>{{calctitle}}</p>
<select v-model="style" name="style">
    <option>Choose style</option>
    <?php foreach ($style as $item) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $item->value; ?>"  v-bind:otype="{value: <?php echo $item->value; ?>, text: '<?php echo $item->text; ?>'}"><?php echo $item->text; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you'll be able to do it with a computed, since you don't store the selected option anywhere, only its value.

Instead, you can create a data item and use the `change` event on the select to pull the selected option and set your data value from its `textContent`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedText: '',
    style: '5'
  },
  methods: {
    updateFromSelectedText(event) {
      const options = event.target.options;
      const selectedOption = options[options.selectedIndex];

      this.selectedText = selectedOption.textContent;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<p>{{selectedText}} and {{style}}</p>
<select v-model="style" name="style" @change="updateFromSelectedText">
    <option>Choose style</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <!--option value="<?php echo $item->value; ?>"  v-bind:otype="{value: <?php echo $item->value; ?>, text: '<?php echo $item->text; ?>'}"><?php echo $item->text; ?></option-->

</select></div>
```

Comment: how is the option value here preserved if i submit the form?

Comment: The value of the `<option>` is bound to `option.value`, so the form would include the numeral as the value of the select.

Comment: i don't have an "options" js object, so i cannot use `v-for="option in options"`

Comment: I've revised it to use hard-coded `<options>`. The `v-for` is not relevant to the issue.

Comment: That works, thanks, but somehow that's a lot of code for such a simple thing...?